# How to eliminate a row based on surrounding values

Tags: python, multiple-columns

I'm pretty new to coding, and I'm having trouble finding a solution for my problem. Currently, I have a program that analyzes a photo to find the centroid values of a grid of dots (~50). Often, the code picks up a few extra data points that are not actually dots.

As I said originally, the dots are on a physical grid, with a few pixels of error (i.e. any two given centroid in the same row or column could differ by as much as 10 pixels). The rows and columns are separated by about 200 pixels.

The camera can move slightly so I cannot tell the program exactly where the dots are.

I would like something that basically says...

```
(where xi and yi are the centroids of the ith dot)

Assume 0th point (smallest x and y) is on the grid.  

for 1-n

if [10 < xi - x(i-1) < 190] and [10 < yi - y(i-1) < 190] 

then delete i

else keep i.
```

I'm attempting something like:

```py
all_data = [ column for column in all_data if not (30  <= all_data[j , 0] -
 all_data[j+1, 0] <= 200) and  (30  <= all_data[j , 1] - all_data[j+1, 1] <= 200)]
```

but I have two issues.  First I don't know how to assume the first point is in the data set already.  Second if I do find an error point, I'm not sure(since I can't get it to run because of the first issue) if this will use the error point as the j-1 value when seeing if the jth value is on the grid(which would result in that value also being thought of as an error.

Comment: What program and coding language is this?

Comment: I'm using Python